# How are free objects constructed?

Tags: haskell, monads, free-monad

So I understand that a free object is defined as being the left-hand side of an adjunction. But how does that lead you to the Haskell definition of such objects?

More concretely: given a "forgetful functor" from the category of monads to the category of endofunctors,

```
newtype Forget m a = Forget (m a)
instance Monad m => Functor (Forget m) where
    fmap f (Forget x) = Forget (liftM f x)
```

then the *free monad* `Free :: (* -> *) -> (* -> *)` is a type admitting (a `Monad` instance and) the following isomorphism:

```
type f ~> g = forall x. f x -> g x

fwd :: (Functor f, Monad m) => (f ~> Forget m) -> (Free f ~> m)
bwd :: (Functor f, Monad m) => (Free f ~> m) -> (f ~> Forget m)

fwd . bwd = id = bwd . fwd
```

If we drop the `Forget`s, for the free monad in `Control.Monad.Free` we have `fwd = foldFree` and `bwd = (. liftF)` (I think?)

But how do these laws lead to the construction found in `Control.Monad.Free`? How do you come up with `data Free f a = Return a | Free (f (Free f a))`? Surely you don't just guess until you come up with something that satisfies the laws? Same question goes for the free category of a graph, the free monoid of a set, and any other free object you care to name.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say a lot of the ones you mention were based on the construction of the free group. Certainly the construction of free monoids and semigroups are simplifications thereof, and free semigroupoids and categories then extend those. Free monads are a bit more of a stretch.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the notion of "free" is as well-defined as you seem to believe.  While I do think the general consensus is that it is indeed a left adjoint of a forgetful functor, the issue lies in what ["forgetful"](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/forgetful+functor) means.  There are clear definitions in some broad-ranging cases, particularly for [concrete categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category).

Universal algebra provides a broad ranging approach which covers almost all "algebraic" structures (over sets).  The upshot is given a "signature" which consists of sorts, operations, and equations, you build a term algebra (i.e. an AST) of the operations and then quotient it by the equivalence relation generated by the equations.  This is the free algebra generated from that signature.  For example, we usually talk about monoids as being a set equipped with an associative multiplication and unit.  In code, the free algebra before quotienting would be:

```
data PreFreeMonoid a
  = Unit
  | Var a
  | Mul (PreFreeMonid a) (PreFreeMonoid a)
```

We would then quotient by the equivalence relation generated from the equations:

```
Mul Unit x = x
Mul x Unit = x
Mul (Mul x y) z = Mul x (Mul y z)
```

But you can show that the resulting quotient type is isomorphic to lists.  In the multi-sorted case, we'd have a family of term algebras, one for each sort.

One way to recast this categorically is to use the notion of a (slightly generalized) [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory).  Given a signature with a set of sorts, *S*, we can build a small category, call it **T**,  whose objects are lists of elements of *S*.  These small categories will be called **theories** in general.  Operations get mapped to arrows whose source and target correspond to the appropriate arities.  We freely add "tupling" and "projection" arrows so that e.g. [*A*,*B*,*A*] becomes the product [*A*]×[*B*]×[*A*].  Finally, we add commutative diagrams (i.e. equations between arrows) correspond to each equation in the signature.  At this point, **T** essentially represents the term algebra(s).  In fact, an actual interpretation or model of this term algebra is just a finite product preserving functor **T** → **Set**, write **Mod**(**T**) for the category of finite product preserving functors from **T** → **Set**.  In the single sorted case, we'd have an underlying set functor, but in general we get a *S*-indexed family of sets, i.e. we have a functor *U* : **Mod**(**T**) → **Set**<sup>*S*</sup> where we're viewing *S* as a discrete category here. *U* is simply *U*(m)(s) = m([s]).  We can actually calculate the left adjoint.  First, we have a family of sets indexed by elements of *S*, call it *G*. Then we need to build a finite product preserving functor **T** → **Set**, but *any* functor into **Set** (i.e. [copresheaf](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presheaf)) is [a colimit of representables](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/co-Yoneda+lemma) which, in this case, means it's a quotient of the following (dependent) sum type:

> Free(*G*)(*s*) = Σ*t*:**T**.**T**(*t*,*s*)×Free(*G*)(*t*)

*If* Free(*G*) is finite product preserving then in the *t* = [*A*,*B*] case, for example, we'd have:

> **T**([*A*,*B*],*s*)×Free(*G*)([*A*,*B*]) = **T**([*A*,*B*],*s*)×Free(*G*)([*A*])×Free(*G*)([*B*])

and we simply define Free(*G*)([*A*]) = *G*(*A*) for each *A* in *S* producing:

> **T**([*A*,*B*],*s*)×Free(*G*)([*A*])×Free(*G*)([*B*]) = **T**([*A*,*B*],*s*)×*G*(*A*)×*G*(*B*)

Altogether this says that, an element of Free(*G*)([*A*]) consists of an arrow of **T** into [*A*] and a list of elements of the appropriate sets corresponding to the source of that arrow, i.e. the arity of the term modulo equations that make it behave sensibly and obey the equations from the signature but which I'm not going to elaborate on.  For the multiplication of a monoid, we'd have an arrow m : [*A*,*A*] → [*A*] and this would lead to a tuples (m, *x*, *y*) where *x* and *y* are elements of *G*(*A*) corresponding to an term like `m(x, y)`.  Recasting this definition of as a recursive one takes looking at the equations we're quotienting by.

There are other things to verify to show that Free ⊣ *U* but it isn't too hard.  Once that's done, *U*∘Free is a monad on **Set**<sup>*S*</sup>.

The nice thing about the Lawvere theory approach is that it is easy to generalize in multiple ways.  One straightforward way is to replace **Set** by some other topos **E**.  It's actually the case that the category of directed multigraphs form a topos, but I don't believe you can (easily) view categories as theories over **Graph**.  A different direction to extend Lawvere theories is to consider [doctrines](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/doctrine) other than finite product preserving functors, in particular finite *limit* preserving functors aka [left exact or lex functors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exact+functor) is an interesting point.  Both small categories and directed multigraphs (which categorists sometimes call [quivers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/quiver)) can be viewed as models of a category with finite limits. There's a straightforward inclusion of the theory of directed multigraphs into the theory of small categories.  This, contravariantly, induces a functor **cat** → **Graph** simply by precomposition.  The [left adjoint of this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+category#free_category_on_a_directed_graph) is then (almost) the [left Kan extensions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kan+extension#GlobalKanExtensions) along that inclusion.  These left Kan extensions will occur in **Set** so ultimately they are just colimits which are just quotients of (dependent) sum types.  (Technically, you need to verify that the resulting Kan extensions are finite limit preserving.  We're also helped by the fact that the models of the theory of graphs are essentially *arbitrary* functors from the theory of graphs.  This happens because the theory of graphs consists only of unary operations.)

None of this helps for free monads though.  However, it turns out that [one construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transfinite+construction+of+free+algebras) subsumes all of these including free monads.  Returning to universal algebra, it's the case that every signature with no equations gives rise to a (polynomial) functor whose [initial algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor) is the free term algebra.  [Lambek's lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor#LambeksTheorem) suggests and it's easy to prove that [the initial algebra is just colimit of repeated applications of the functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor#AdameksTheorem).  The above general result is based on a similar approach and the relevant case for free monads is the [unpointed endofunctor case](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transfinite+construction+of+free+algebras#free_algebras_for_unpointed_endofunctors), in which you start to see the definition of `Free` that you gave, but actually working it out fully requires unfolding many constructions.

Frankly, though, what I'm pretty sure actually happened in the FP world is the following.  If you look at `PreFreeMonoid`, it's actually a free monad.  `PreFreeMonoid Void` is the initial algebra for the functor the monoid signature (minus the equations) would give rise to.  If you are familiar with using functors for initial algebras and you even start thinking about universal algebra, you are almost certainly going to end up defining a type like `data Term f a = Var a | Op (f (Term f a))`.  It's easy to verify this is a monad once you think to ask the question.  If you're even vaguely familiar with the relationship monads have to algebraic structures or to term substitution, then you may ask the question quite quickly.  The same construction can be stumbled upon from a programming language implementation perspective.  If you just directly set your goal to be deriving the free monad construction in Haskell, there are several intuitive ways to arrive at the right definition especially combined with some equational/parametricity-driven reasoning.  In fact, the "monoid object in the category of endofunctors" one is quite suggestive.

<sub>('really wish this StackExchange had MathJax support.)</sub>

Comment: "But you can show that the resulting quotient type is isomorphic to lists." It really isn't. For instance, if ｘ ＝ Ｍｕｌ ｘ （Ｖａｒ ＇ａ＇）, then there is no list that this is equivalent to. The issue is that the associative law isn't infinitely associative. See "Free Monoids in Haskell" http://comonad.com/reader/2015/free-monoids-in-haskell/